# Reusable Hygen generator with .hygen.js extension

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm attempting to share a hygen generator for project to use with `hygen-add`. However, this generator requires some extensions via helper functions created using the `.hygen.js` extension point. Is there any way to share these helper functions with my hygen generator without requiring users of the generator to add a `.hygen.js` file to their repository?

I've tried putting a `.hygen.js` file in the generator directory.

Comment: It appears it is common among hygen generators to add an "init" generator that creates a `.hygen.js` file. That option isn't too bad.